# Android application crashes every other compilation/launch

Tags: java, android

For some reason every other time I compile my app, the app crashes and I get the following error.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference
        at com.mycompany.talk.Fragments.MapFragment$1.onLocationChanged(MapFragment.java:68)
```

I am not sure how to fix this error nor what's causing it. It works fine on some compilations and launches but on others, the app crashes. The error occurs in my "MapFragment" class.

onLocationChanged(Location) method.

onLocationChanged()

```
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {

                /*
                Updates to our map may need to be taken place here. Need to listen to other devices in the area.
                 */

                Log.e("Latitude: ", "" + location.getLatitude());
                Log.e("Longitude: ", "" + location.getLongitude());
                maps.clear(); //Clear the map of any  existing markers
                mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                MarkerOptions mp1 = new MarkerOptions();//Instantiate a new "MarkerOptions" where we will be able to define a...
                                                        //...marker

                mp1.position(mLatLng);
                mp1.title("You");
                maps.addMarker(mp1);//Finally add the marker to the map
                maps.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));//Move camera to markers location using our "latLng" variable
                maps.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));// Zoom, (between 2.0 - 21.0) the higher, the more zoomed in

            }
        }
```

MapFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.mycompany.talk.R;


public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
int radius = 20;
private GoogleMap maps;
LatLng mLatLng;
LocationManager mLocationManager;
LocationListener mLocationListener;

public LatLng getLatLng(){
    return mLatLng;
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sfm = getFragmentManager();
    mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if(!mSupportMapFragment.isAdded())
    sfm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map_frag,mSupportMapFragment).commit();

   else if(mSupportMapFragment.isAdded())
        sfm.beginTransaction().hide(mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    else
        sfm.beginTransaction().show(mSupportMapFragment).commit();

    //LocationManager mLocationManager;
   // LocationListener mLocationListener;
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {

                /*
                Updates to our map may need to be taken place here. Need to listen to other devices in the area.
                 */

                Log.e("Latitude: ", "" + location.getLatitude());
                Log.e("Longitude: ", "" + location.getLongitude());

                if(maps != null) {
                    maps.clear(); //Clear the map of any  existing markers
                }
                mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());//This is an Update!!!!!!!!! Might not work!!!!!
                MarkerOptions mp1 = new MarkerOptions();//Instantiate a new "MarkerOptions" where we will be able to define a...
                                                        //...marker

                mp1.position(mLatLng);//This is an Update!!!!!!!!! Might not work!!!!!
                mp1.title("You");
                maps.addMarker(mp1);//Finally add the marker to the map
                maps.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));//Move camera to markers location using our "latLng" variable
                maps.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));// Zoom, (between 2.0 - 21.0) the higher, the more zoomed in

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,mLocationListener);//THIS IS AN UPDATE!
    //Need more precise coordinates..............
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    maps = map;
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    Log.e("RESUME","onResume called");
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onStop(){
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    Log.e("PAUSE", "Coordinates stopped");
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    Log.e("PAUSE", "Coordinates stopped");
    super.onPause();
 }
}
```

Comment: where is maps defined in onLocationChanged and it should be something like private Google maps = new Maps(); or whatever the constructor you want to use

Comment: Maybe the location changes before the map is ready.

Comment: I believe it's actually instantiated as a global and defined in "onMapReady(GoogleMap map)" @therealprashant

Comment: could you just console.log(map) at the line of error to verify yourself . That will help I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maps` is initialized and accessed in two different callback methods `onLocationChanged(...)` and `onMapReady(...)` which means that if the location changes before the map is ready (`onLocationChanged(...)` is called before `onMapReady(...)`), `maps` will be `null`. To resolve this, you can check if `maps` is `null` before accessing it. Ex:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null && maps != null) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have fixed the problem. I was confused on when onMapReady(..)  gets called.